# Why does providing the initialfile argument to tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename unselect Listbox elements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

## Problem

When I provide the `initialfile` keyword argument to `tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename` all my `Listbox` elements are unselected.

## MCVE

I'm using Python 2.7.15+ with Tkinter version 8.6 under Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog
import ttk

# set up a box with some selected elements
root = tk.Tk()
box = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
for s in ('this', 'is a', 'minimal', 'example'):
    box.insert(tk.END, s)
box.selection_set(1)
box.selection_set(3)
box.grid()

# hitting this button does not reset the current selection in box
ttk.Button(root, text='no initialfile',
    command=tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename).grid()

# hitting this button resets the current selection in box - why?
ttk.Button(root, text='with initialfile',
    command=lambda: tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile='XXX')).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the fact that by default only one set of text can be selected at a time. That is because tk widgets export the selection to the clipboard, and only one item can be on the clipboard at a time.

You can prevent this from happening by setting `exportselection` to `False` on your listbox, removing the connection between the listbox selection and the clipboard.

```
box = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, exportselection=False)
```